# Renew kerberos ticket in tmux

Tags: tmux, authentication, kerberos

I have two servers, `server 1` and `server 2`. To login onto each server, I need a valid kerberos ticket, the same ticket is valid for both servers. If I run a `tmux` session on `server 1`, with several windows open and the kerberos ticket expires, it's enough to get a new ticket in one window only, all other windows will then use this newly validated kerberos ticket. On `server 2`, however, the kerberos tickets are not shared, i.e. I need to get a new ticket in each window separately.

I figured this is due to the servers having different ticket caches. If I do `klist` on `server 1`, I get

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_4350_NGboq23888
```

on **all** windows. On `server 2`, the last random string is different for each window.

I checked the man page of `krb5.conf`:

> default_ccache_name:
>          This relation specifies the  name  of  the  default  credential  cache.   The
>          default  is  FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}.   This relation is subject to parameter
>          expansion (see below).  New in release 1.11.

and it is true that `4350` is my `uid`, but I don't see a reference to the random string after that. The `default_ccache_name` is not set in `/etc/krb5.conf` on any of the servers.

My question is: How can I set up `server 2` such, that it's sufficient to get a kerberos ticket only in one `tmux` window, and it will be valid for all other `tmux` windows as well. Following my reasoning above, I think this question boils down to: How can I define what ticket cache will be used on my servers?